# what is default value of array of vectors?

Tags: c++, arrays

My class has such member:

```
struct Field
{
int Index;
std::string Name;
FieldType Type;
int Length;
};

private:
std::vector<Field> setAsList[Fieldset_COUNT];
```

- What is default value of each item in array?
- Should I create new `vector` for each item in array?
- if items in this array `nullable`?

Comment: We need more information on what type of object or variable `Field` is.

Comment: The elements in your array of vectors must be initialized.  And unlike C#, C++ has no native notion of "nullable".

Comment: 1. A bunch of empty vectors. 2. You already did. 3. Not in the sense you're probably thinking. If by "nullable" you mean "can be emptied to have no content" then yes, `setAsList[i].clear();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The default value is an empty vector.

2) No you have already created the vectors, you might want to resize them at some point, but you don't need to create them.

3) No such thing in C++.

I see you're still making the adjustment to working without pointers/references.

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<int> testVector;
vector<long> testVector(10);
vector<float> testVector(5,1.0);
```

The first syntax declares an empty vector capable of storing the integer datatype.

The second declares a vector with storage space for 10 long integers, each of which is intialized to the default value for the type.

The final line declares a vector with storage for 5 floats, and initializes each of their values to 1.0. Any valid type can be used for any of the constructors.